Angular v18 does not accept .jpg files?
I tried displaying an image in Angular v18 but it never showed up until I tried using a .png which to my surprise worked as expected
I also placed both images in the same folder (/public) because according to angular.json its a replacement for the assets folder that we know from earlier versions.
"assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],

 <img src="/Scree.png">


issue not reproducible stackblitz please reproduce and share back!

Seems to be a local issue / bug on my computer because it works on other systems
